# Enable Associated Domains, it enables com.apple.SafariKeychain

Tags: ios, xcode

I enabled Associated Domains in Capabilities in Xcode, and it creates a ".entitlements" file as expected. But it also modified a `project.pbxproj` file, adds `com.apple.SafariKeychain = {enabled = 1;}`

So I am just curious, why it is enabled, is it useful for some reason?

I couldn't find any documentation about this.

Comment: When you enable that capability, it adds a <app-name>.entitlements file to your project, hence modifying your project.pbxproj. (I'm not sure where you are seeing the enabled = 1 being set)

Comment: @NitinAlabur if you use git, you can see your project root -> <project-name> -> project.pbxproj file is changed

Comment: yeah, I see that now. I think if you enable Assoicated domains, you have the ability to add webcredentials:yourURL.com to the domains list, which lets your app access safari keychain for your domain. If a user has saved a password for your domain, and you want the user to be able to use that password in app, this will be useful

Answer (score 7):

***Note: Updated for iOS 12***

That entitlement is used for multiple purposes.  It covers any feature where your app needs to establish a verified connection to a web domain.  This verification is accomplished by placing a static JSON file (called `apple-app-site-association`) at the root level of your domain which contains your app's fully-qualified App ID, with keys and configuration to enable specific functionality.

It covers a few actual iOS features:

- **[Shared Web Credentials.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/security/shared_web_credentials)** The identifier `com.apple.SafariKeychain` actually refers to the original purpose of the Associated Domains capability, which was to enable native app access to credentials stored in iCloud Keychain for your web domain.  If a user has already logged in to your web site and saved their password in iCloud Keychain, this feature allows your native app to use those stored credentials.
- **[Password AutoFill.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill)** ***Available in iOS 12.*** Password AutoFill takes the behavior added to web sites with Shared Web Credentials, and extends it into native apps in a robust way.  By establishing Associated Domains for you app, and adding metadata to your text fields, iOS can automatically enter saved web credentials into your native app.  when creating a new account or changing passwords, Password Autofill can offer strong password suggestions, based on your organization's password rules.  It can also assist the user by automatically filling in a multi-factor authentication code sent via text message, if it can find a field designated for entering that information.
- **[Universal Links.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html)**  At its simplest, this feature is a secure replacement for the old custom-scheme-based method of launching one application from another, or from a web link.  When used to its fullest, it allows you to draw parallels between the information architecture of your website and your native app.  When a user taps a web link for your domain, your native app can be launched in order to handle that link.  If the app is not installed, a Smart Banner will be presented with a link to the App Store.
- **[Web Browser–to–Native App Handoff.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/AdoptingHandoff/AdoptingHandoff.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014338-CH2-SW21)** This is a passive version of Universal Links.  If a user is browsing your website on a macOS or iOS device, and you have created a site association for the page they're viewing, they will see a Handoff icon on their iOS lock screen which will let them open your app and, optionally, navigate to the native version of the web page they were viewing.